# Generating a migration using a custom rails generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I took some time to learn how rails generators works and I managed to create one that copies some files and changes others. I call it this way:

```
rails generate menu test
```

But I need to make it generate a migration too, to create a table and add fields to it, something like:

```
rails generate menu test content:text
```

The number of arguments may vary, but it is a given that it'll always have an ID and a title column.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want:

```
$ rails generate scaffold test content:text
```

then have a look [this Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#creating-your-first-generator). It provides information such as:

> [...] notice that we are inheriting from Rails::Generators::NamedBase instead of Rails::Generators::Base. This means that our generator expects at least one argument, which will be the name of the initializer, and will be available in our code in the variable name.
>
> We can see that by invoking the description of this new generator (don't forget to delete the old generator file):
>
> ```
> $ rails generate initializer --help  
> Usage:  
>     rails generate initializer NAME [options]
> ```